# How to prevent Command-I/Command-Shift-I from opening Mac Mail when in browser?

Tags: keyboard, safari, google-chrome, defaults, keybindings

When in a browser (Chrome or Safari), the following keyboard shortcuts both launch the MacOS Mail app, and there doesn't seem to be any way to change or disable them.

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Cmd-I / ⌘-I is particularly annoying because of course that is much more often used to italicize text.

Is there any way to disable this shortcut?

Comment: Does this only happen in Safari or also in other application?

Comment: Ah, good question!  I assumed it was global, but it only happens in Safari (or Chrome).  And actually, I was using Chrome.

Comment: It's got even worse now. They've changed it in Yosemite to ⌘-I, when it used to work as a setting for forcing in-text type as _italics_ when supported. It's the most inane shortcut ever. Who the hell needs to frequently email links to people? And whoever those annoying people are _(i.e. my family members)_, I wish they would stop!

Comment: The answer here solved it for Safari: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251230865

Comment: A lot of people say that this can be solved by creating a custom keyboard shortcut for "Email This Page" that overwrites the default ⌘I -- but I've done this, and although the new shortcut shows up as changed in the Safari menus, ⌘I STILL OPENS MAIL. Argh.

Comment: @Bowen Not sure I understand your recent edits. The original question was about Safari and Chrome, what is the idea behind removing the Chrome reference here?

Comment: @nohillside thanks -- I think it would make sense to split out the question & answer because clearly there are solutions that solve this for Chrome that do not solve it for Safari.

Comment: @bowen That‘s kind of hard to do for an eight year-old question which got answers for both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can change the shortcuts from System Preferences:

[image]

If you want to disable the shortcuts, edit the NSUserKeyEquivalents dictionaries directly:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Email Page Location' '\0'
defaults write com.google.Chrome.canary NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Email Page Location' '\0'
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Email Link to This Page' '\0' 'Email This Page' '\0'
```

Then quit and reopen Chrome and Safari to apply the changes.

Comment: As of El Capitan, I no longer see anything but "All Applications -> Show Help menu" in that dialog.

Comment: In El Capitan, you have to hit the + button at the bottom, then in the dialog box that pops up, select Google Chrome from the Application dropdown. Fill in the Menu Title and Keyboard Shortcut as the screen shot above shows. Despite my comment below, this GUI method works for me again in El Capitan, but I'm still unable to disable this shortcut in Safari.

Comment: Seems the "Menu text" in newer Chrome is `Email Link`.  Changes should take effect while chrome is still running.

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling the shortucts per your suggestion doesn’t work in Safari. It still gets triggered.

Comment: I've tried disabling this both by setting an alternative shortcut using the Keyboard System Preferences and also using the command line method above, but Cmd-I still opens Mail from Safari. So lame! (I'm running MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2)

Comment: Even worse in MacOS Ventura, the "Email This Page" and "Email Link to This Page" menu items are simply gone from Safari, but the Cmd-I shortcut STILL opens Mail.app 

Answer (score 33):

Taking a look at [Chrome's keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3001914?hl=en#mac_webpages) helps.

<kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is to "Email the current page". It's a bit annoying because it's so close to the developer tools (<kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

Comment: I don't see this shortcut listed anymore on the link yet this behavior exists. Strange.

Comment: By using [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108129/284862), you can make `CMD` + `Shift` + `I` open up Developer Tools. (Create a new Google Chrome shortcut with `Menu Title: Developer Tools`)

Comment: @OJ7, this disables Chrome's default CMD + Opt + I, right?
Is there a way to make them both open Developer Tools?

Comment: @DmitriiKuznetsov right, this replaces it. I haven't tried this, but you may be able to [use this](https://superuser.com/questions/402320/multiple-keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-same-command-in-os-x) to create multiple shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

I am a Linux user when using a desktop but OS X for laptops. My need is to insure that I have the same shortcut for the Inspector using Chrome. It was very inconvenient to have the Mail.app popup each time that I would confuse the shortcuts.

I should add that in order to make Linux closer to OSX I swap the control and the alt keys on the Linux side. This allows me to use Ctrl-c, Ctrl-v and many other shortcuts in the more ergonomic position of the command key, e.g. OS X Cmd-c, Cmd-v. In the pictures you will see that I have mapped Ctrl-Shift-I which would not make sense in the Linux side otherwise.

Here is my shortcuts setup

[image]

The important part of the setting is to know that the OSX shortcut must be mapped to the exact name of the menu entry. I stated that I am using High Sierra because "Email Link" is the menu label. This could also be dependent on the Chrome version I suppose. Make sure the spelling is identical.

The steps to reproduce are

1. Apple Menu System Preferences ...
2. Keyboard Menu
3. Shortcuts Tab
4. App Shortcuts from the left Pane
5. Click the Plus sign under the right pane
6. Select YOUR APP from the applications list, in my case Chrome
7. Add the name of the menu label, in my case Email Link
8. Add some shortcut you will not use, in my case Cmd-Shift-E
9. Then, add another shortcut for the target operation, in my case Developer Tools
10. Add the desired shortcut, in my case Cmd-Shift-I

Answer (score 5):

The command-line solution [given in another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108129) eventually worked for me but I needed to do one more thing:

after `defaults write com.google.Chrome NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Email Page Location' '\0'`, 
I entered the command: 
`killall cfprefsd` (and `killall Finder` for good measure).

This stopped the annoying <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut on Chrome from creating a new mail message, but I can't get it to stop happening in Safari, unfortunately.

`killall cfprefsd` clears the preferences cache
`killall Finder` restarts the Finder

The GUI method described at the top didn't work at all for me, but maybe because I didn't clear the prefs cache.

Comment: This worked in El Capitan!

Comment: this doesn't work in *macOS Sierra 10.12.5* and its really annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately **none** of the answers given here were able to prevent <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> from triggering Email This Page in *Safari* for me (running macOS Sierra). The *only* way I have been able to prevent that behavior is by using [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to map <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to an empty AppleScript. The script must be stored in `~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Safari` to prevent it from disabling use of the shortcut for italics in other applications.

Unfortunately this approach has the side effect of disabling the use of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to toggle italics in Safari where that is its default behavior, such as in Google Docs or in this answer box on AskDifferent. For me that's worth avoiding being thrown into my email inbox whenever I try to italicize text in a text box in Safari that doesn't support it.

Comment: Ideally the AppleScript could detect when ⌘I would cause italic behavior and somehow "forward" the shortcut in that case. I don't have time to figure out how that would work at the moment but I'd welcome any comments on how this might be achieved!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is not working on my MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra system.

I found a solution to disable <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> in Chrome:

1. Install the Chrome extension [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck).
2. Open the Shortkeys's preference panel, add a `command+shift+i` shortcut like below:

   [image: Shortkeys for Chrome screenshot]
3. Restart Chrome.

Now you can say goodbye to the annoying Mac Mail!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net) to override the shortcuts (globally or for any specific application).

Given I was already using this app, it's been the solution for me since none of the other answers mentioned here worked for me (High Sierra), and I didn't want to install new software.

Comment: How did you exactly set this up in BTT?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I could find is to assign the keyboard shortcut to activate one of your installed extensions

**chrome://extensions/shortcuts**

Comment: This worked great! Fortunately I had an extension installed that would alphabetise my bookmarks on activation so there is no harm in activating that particular extension every time I use the wrong keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Glorfindel worked great for me! I'm suprised that it's not voted much better.

To stop this pesky Mail app from launching you just need to assign it's shortcut (Cmd-Shift-I) to something else:

1) assign it to making a copy of the screen to the clipboard - it stops it in Safari, Chrome, Finder (looks like everywhere)

[image: assigning to Copy Printscreen]

2) assign it to launching Developer Tools in Chrome - the only disadvantage Mail will still be launched in Safari - you get Developer Tools always!

[image: assigning to Developer Tools]

Comment: I think you're talking about Chelista's answer.. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355265/313842

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I've found to work for Safari is to **change the default mail handler  app**.

I set mine to Safari itself, which isn't quite perfect but at least it means that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (when not trapped by a handler for *italics*) doesn't open Mail.

As detailed in the top answer of [Set default mail client in macOS without adding an email account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261881/set-default-mail-client-in-macos-without-adding-an-email-account/422772) you can use [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) to change the default mail app, as illustrated here ↓

[image: Screen shot of SwiftDefaultApps preferences pane]