# How do I remove the Cmd+Shift+I shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> launches the Mail app (which can't be removed), but I can't find that shortcut in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Where does that shortcut come from, and how can I remove it?

Comment: Just as an aside, a) I had no idea this shortcut existed, and b) this launches whatever you have set as the default mail program in Mail.app > Preferences > General > Default email reader. For me it launched a Gmail tab in my web browser.

Comment: @tubedogg: I never use Mail.app and don't need it. I find it maddening that I'm forced to create a bogus account in order to access its Preferences menu.

Comment: If you have another mail program that you use, it likely has a setting to make it the default without needing to open Mail. Otherwise, yes. (Note there is no "none" setting in Mail, if that's what you're looking for.)

Comment: On my machine <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is mapped to "Go" -> "iCloud Drive". I do not get the mail launching behaviour. I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.6 and generally don't mess with any keyboard shortcut presets. All the google images of the "Go" menu in El Capitan seem to show the same shortcut.  What OS version are you running @tubedog ?

Comment: Just found that my question is a duplicate of [How to prevent Command-I/Command-Shift-I from opening Mac Mail when in browser?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/how-to-prevent-command-i-command-shift-i-from-opening-mac-mail-when-in-browser). Please close. [#honor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334484/downvoted-and-censored-after-asking-for-feedback-in-the-chat#comment394880_334484)