# In MacOS Catalina 10.15 on Safari, How do you disable Command-I from composing a new Mail message?

Tags: keyboard, safari, mail.app, shortcut

I realize a similar question to this has been asked, but it's not the same. The answers in that question are for older versions of MacOS. I'm asking this question specifically for MacOS Catalina 10.15.

Comment: Seems like a pretty tough thing to do without removing Command I functionality completely.

Comment: I have macOS 10.15.5 (as of last night). In the `System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` tab, there is no shortcut registered for either of the "New email" options. When I select some text from this page in my browser & use `command-i`, I get a "page info" window displayed - probably a Firefox shortcut(?). My point being that perhaps you set this - perhaps inadvertently via a mail app?

Answer (score 1):

macOS has a built in method for changing/adding keyboard shortcuts

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
3. Click the "+" button and select Safari from the Application drop down menu
4. In the Menu Title box enter the **EXACT** wording of that menu selection "Email This Page" (it must be *exact*, capitalization, spaces, etc)
5. Assign a keyboard shortcut you would never use, like Shift-Command-Option-Ctrl-I
6. Click Add and close system preferences

Note now that the Command-I in that menu has been changed to whatever you set it to, allowing you to set Command-I to something else, or just leaving it that way so you won't accidentally use it.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be working. Super annoying. It even shows in the safari menu item ‘Email This Page’ as my set command (that I wouldn’t use), yet still when I press Command-I it still composes an email. I made sure to restart and shut off my computer. And closed the apps

Comment: Strange, worked fine on my Mac. I did only use COMMAND-OPTION-I... strange. Sry!

Comment: On Mojave - I can confirm that this **should** work… but doesn't. Both the replacement key command [im my case ti tried a silly cmd/shift/ctrl/opt/F15 as well as the simple cmd/shift/i just to be really sure. Both the replacement **and** the original still trigger the action. idk why.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just updated to macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and it still doesn't work. I have the same problem

Comment: I had to relaunch Safari but it does work. Who at Apple thought this would be a nice feature?! ‍♂️

Comment: does not work -- and, even worse in MacOS Ventura, the "Email This Page" and "Email Link to This Page" menu items are simply gone from Safari, but the Cmd-I shortcut STILL opens Mail.app 

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I've found to work for Safari is to **change the default mail handler app**.

I set mine to Safari itself, which isn't quite perfect but at least it means that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (when not trapped by a handler for *italics*) doesn't open Mail.

As detailed in the top answer of [Set default mail client in macOS without adding an email account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261881/set-default-mail-client-in-macos-without-adding-an-email-account/422772) you can use [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) to change the default mail app, as illustrated here ↓

[image: Screen shot of SwiftDefaultApps preferences pane]

Answer (score 0):

You can remap <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to a different action in Safari that is less annoying than composing a new email. For example, I've set mine to open the share sheet which can be easily escaped out of.

Go to *System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts* and map <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Safari to open "Share...":

[image: system settings]

Or you can run the following shell command and then relaunch Safari:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Share...' '@i'
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these to your shortcuts, and **try restarting your computer**. It should work on Catalina.

[image]

EDIT: It seems to be [a bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394815/197118) that this method won't actually work on Safari, even on macOS 11 (unless they fix the bug before it's officially released).

Comment: It still doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Damn! Did you try restarting? I tried this method and it didn't work immediately, but I noticed after a few days the Command I shortcut went away. Now it shows the above shortcuts in the menu bar. Maybe you need to restart your cache somehow as well after restarting, or potentially reset your safari preferences (when I carried Lightroom preferences over I noticed the custom shortcut was carried along with the .plist file, and it ignored my system preferences setting)

Comment: @Andrew See my updated answer

Comment: Still with Safari 16 and Mac OS 12.6 these are set, show in the Safari "File > Share" menu with the new shortcuts but still CMD+I is bound. So the bug is still present.