# Can't disable command + shift + I to open mail

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, email, google-chrome

I followed the answer for disabling command + shift + I to open mail here: [How to prevent Command-I/Command-Shift-I from opening Mac Mail when in browser?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/how-to-prevent-command-i-command-shift-i-from-opening-mac-mail-when-in-browser)
[image]

However, this doesn't work for me. I restarted Chrome afterwards. Has there been a change recently with OSX/Chrome? Since I'm used to ctrl + shift + I on Windows, I open Mail a lot.

Also, is it safe to delete programs like Mail and Safari? Since Apple makes them so hard to delete, I'd imagine the OS might throw errors if they're deleted?

Comment: It's best to have only one question per question - answer to the first below; but as your second question has already been asked many times, then quickly - no, you cannot remove Apple's default apps. a) it will not let you & b) if you did manage it the system would refuse to boot up until you reinstalled the OS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the *exact wording* in the Menu item… In Chrome it's "Email Link"

[image]

Type the exact wording into the Shortcuts Control Panel & add your changed shortcut…

[image]

You can check this is then reflected in the original Menu item

[image]

BTW, there's no need to restart, or indeed do anything. You can check the new shortcut appears in the menu even before you close the control panel.

BTW II, unless you by some uncanny circumstance actually have a menu item entitled 'fsjdskfhdsjkfhdslkfj' then this entry will do absolutely nothing at all.

[image]